# Notification Badge In UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, apple-push-notifications

Currently my app receives notifications about updates to an RSS feed. If the user opens the app from the notification, it opens to the correct view controller. If the user does not acknowledge the notification and opens the app from the app icon, when the user opens the menu within the app, the table view cell for that rss feed has a badge icon with the applicationIconBadgeNumber. Once that row is selected, the badge on that cell goes away and the applicationIconBadgeNumber is reset. My question is about wanting to send notifications about other info within the app such as member benefits. How can I differentiate which row in the table view gets the badge? Say the user gets a notification about a member benefit. I would want the badge to appear in the member benefits row of the table view, but if there is a notification from the RSS feed, badge the appropriate row.

Here is how I'm currently adding the badge for the RSS feed row.

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (!(indexPath.row == 0))
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }

    badgeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]];

    actionAlertBadge = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:badgeNumber withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor] withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor] withBadgeFrame:NO withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor redColor] withScale:1.0 withShining:NO withShadow:NO];
    actionAlertBadge.frame = CGRectMake(83, 6, 30, 30);

    if ([badgeNumber isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        actionAlertBadge.hidden = YES;
    }

    if (actionAlertBadge.hidden == NO)
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                cell.accessoryView = actionAlertBadge;
            }
        }
    }
```

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            ActionAlertsViewController *actionAlerts = [[ActionAlertsViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
            [actionAlerts setWebViewController:wvc];
            [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];
            actionAlertBadge.hidden = YES;
            [tableView reloadData];
            navController = [[KFBNavControllerViewController alloc]initWithRootViewController:actionAlerts];

            [UIView transitionWithView:appDelegate.window
                              duration:0.5
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                            animations:^{
                                appDelegate.window.rootViewController = navController;
                            }
                            completion:nil];
        }
```

EDIT: Here is how I'm trying to accomplish this but it is not working because my notificationType string in my table view is NULL.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UA_LINFO(@"Received remote notification: %@", userInfo);

    // Send the alert to UA so that it can be handled and tracked as a direct response. This call
    // is required.
    [[UAPush shared]appReceivedRemoteNotification:userInfo applicationState:application.applicationState];

    // Optionally provide a delegate that will be used to handle notifications received while the app is running
    // [UAPush shared].delegate = your custom push delegate class conforming to the UAPushNotificationDelegate protocol

    // Reset the badge after a push received (optional)
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];

    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];

    NSString *alertMsg = @"";

    if ([apsInfo valueForKey:@"alert"] != NULL) {
        alertMsg = [apsInfo valueForKey:@"alert"];

        if ([alertMsg containsString:@"ACTION ALERT"]) {
            notificationType = @"action alert";
        }
        else if ([alertMsg containsString:@"MEMBER BENEFIT"]) {
            notificationType = @"member benefit";
        }
    }
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSString *notificationType = appDelegate.notificationType;
    // NSLog(@"notificationType menu table: %@", notificationType);
    badgeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]];
    actionAlertBadge = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:badgeNumber withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor] withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor] withBadgeFrame:NO withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor redColor] withScale:1.0 withShining:NO withShadow:NO];
    actionAlertBadge.frame = CGRectMake(83, 6, 30, 30);

    if ([badgeNumber isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        actionAlertBadge.hidden = YES;
    }

    if (actionAlertBadge.hidden == NO) {
        if ([notificationType isEqualToString:@"action alert"]) {
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                    cell.accessoryView = actionAlertBadge;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ([notificationType isEqualToString:@"member benefit"]) {
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                if (indexPath.row == 5) {
                    cell.accessoryView = actionAlertBadge;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can select depending on properties of cell e.g if(cell.title==@"RSS"){do this}.

Comment: @FawadMasud, I know that. The issue is determining the contents of the notification so the correct cell is badged.

Answer (score 0):

First, while sending notification, you should add a field of type in the notification. You will get json dictionary like this

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"type":"rss","text":"Hello, world!"},"sound":"default","badge":3}}
```

Get the type value in function (if the app is running)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary     *)dict {    
// get the type information out of the dictionary 
// now you can perform depending on this type.
 }
```

If the app is not running,then according to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)

"If the app is not running when a push notification arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to handle that push notification. Instead, your implementation of the **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** or **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method needs to get the push notification payload data and respond appropriately."

Get your dictionary in **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method.

Comment: to update your variable "notificationType" in table view class, you can use delegate methods or you can store it where it can be accessible to all classes e.g. user defaults.

Comment: I tried using user defaults but it still doesn't work. It's like I'm doing something wrong in didReceiveRemoteNotification: but I'm not sure what.

Comment: are you getting notification type in didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Comment: I put NSLog statements in didReceiveRemoteNotification: but I never see them.

Comment: It means you are not getting dictionary. Then how are you getting badge numbers?

Comment: This is where I assign badgeNumber in my table view: badgeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]];

Comment: It looks like didReceiveRemoteNotification: only gets called if the app is in the foreground. Can I call it if the app is in the background or not running at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64500/discussion-between-fawad-masud-and-user2029585).

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate, first make a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *notificationType;
```

Then, in your

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

use:

```
self.notificationType = @"action alert";
self.notificationType = @"member benefit";
```

and in your CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (actionAlertBadge.hidden == NO) {
    if ([appDelegate.notificationType isEqualToString:@"action alert"]) {
       ....
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.notificationType isEqualToString:@"member benefit"]) {
       ....
    }
```

On a side note, I would suggest trying to refrain from string comparisions and use something like enums.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the notificationType in your appDelegate? because your code in your applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification doesn't seem to imply that. (notificationtype = instead of self.notificationType).

Comment: I have changed it to self.notificationType and it still does not work.